# Bullets wont disappear from unordered list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

How do I get rid of the bullets next to the list items.  The   list-style-type is set to none.  The bullets were not there when I had the CSS inside the HTML file.  They showed up when I separated the CSS from the HTML.
My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navBarStyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<ul>

  <li><a href="http://www..com/" target="mainFrame">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www..com/events.html" target="mainFrame">Schedule</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www..com/results.html" target="mainFrame">Results</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www..com/leagueinfo.html" target="mainFrame">League</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www..com/map.html" target="mainFrame">Map</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www..com/membership1.html" target="mainFrame">Membership</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www..com/workdates2014.html" target="mainFrame">Workdates</a></li>
</ul>



</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Papyrus Regular;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  color: white; 
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;

  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 50px;
    padding: 1px;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey; }
  
  }

  
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your css syntax - } two times.
Also, you don't need to use html tag  in your .css file

Comment: Thank you, I removed the extra "}" and my problem was solved.  I also removed the html tags.